# How to cancel primary print dialog from poping up

Tags: javascript, printing, cancellation

I try to chancel a print event with pure JavaScript. For this, i have created the following code:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeprint", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('default print canceled');
    // Code to open new page and print from there
});
```

I can see in Dev Console the output *'default print canceled'* and the code after that is executed. However before that, also the standard print dialog opens. But the standard dialog should not come up, since i stopped that with `preventDefault();`. There is no error in Dev Console. Can someone please tell me, what im doing wrong?

Comment: This is not possible. The print dialog is a opened by the browser and not available to JS. In addition, the `beforeprint` event is non-cancellable, so `preventDefault()`/`return false` will have no effect on it.

Comment: Many thx. I have solved this issue a little bit different now.